# Reactions between aqueous or solid LiOH

Tags: aqueous-solution

I've been working on a project to absorb CO$_2$ from fossil fuel power plants.  I found these reactions:

$$\ce{2Li(s) + 2H2O(l) → 2 LiOH(aq) + H2(g)} \tag{1} $$

$$\ce{2 LiOH(s) + CO_2(g) → Li2CO_3(s) + H2O(l)} \tag{2}$$

The first one returns an aqueous solution of $\ce{LiOH}$, and the second one requires solid $\ce{LiOH}$. I was wondering if it's possible to use the aqueous solution in the second equation, or does it have to be solid?  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would actually produce a faster reaction to have the $\ce{LiOH}$ in a aqueous solution rather than having it as a solid. all you would do is bubble the $\ce{CO2}$ through the solution and it will go cloudy. you've probably done a similar thing but with $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ to form calcium carbonate as a test for $\ce{ CO2}$.

Comment: The problem, of course, is that the aqueous solution requires carrying a lot of water weight around to get the needed absorption capacity.  Using solid lithium hydroxide is more an engineering decision than a scientific one.

Comment: If the aqueous solution is used, does LiOH have to be the monohydrate?  Or is it possible to have aqueous, anhydrous LiOH?

Comment: well anhydrous and hydrated crystals are referring to water trapped within the crystal structure when the material is a solid. so when you dissolve it into water the struture of the lattice is broken down so it doesn't matter if it hydrated or not as any water trapped in the crystal structure will just become part of the solution.